# Как сделать так, чтобы GUI не зависало?

Tags: winapi, gui, c++

Есть программа, Windows-32 проект, написанная на WinAPI + С++. По нажатию на кнопку, в оконной процедуре вызывается функция, которая выполняет некий массивный объем вычислений. 
Нужно сделать так, чтобы вовремя выполнения этих вычислений GUI программы не "зависал". Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: Через поток

Comment: ТОЛЬКО потоки!

Comment: Создать отдельный поток, для функции с вычислениями.

Comment: Только через поток!

Comment: Через поток!

Comment: И еще раз потоки! )

Comment: Потоки, потоки, потоки, потоки, потоки, потоки, скучно.
Можно сделать еще одно невидимое окно и внутри его функции WndProc считать.

Comment: @igumnov, в Win16, где не то что потоков – процессов ещё не было, создание невидимого окна (или, упаси господи, новой задачи) ещё имело смысл. Но сейчас?..

Comment: @igumnov, про «упаси господи» – отдельную задачу, пусть и дочернюю, пользователь может легко завершить, что требует специальной обработки подобных случаев.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Creating Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516(v=vs.85).aspx)

Пример вызова потока на Windows API. Для GUI приложения надо поступить также, вынеся длительную операцию из GUI-потока в отдельный поток.

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <tchar.h> 
#include <strsafe.h>

DWORD WINAPI MyThreadFunction(LPVOID lpParam);

typedef struct MyData {
    int value;
} MYDATA, * PMYDATA;

int _tmain() {

    PMYDATA pMyData = (PMYDATA) HeapAlloc(
        GetProcessHeap(),
        HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,
        sizeof(MYDATA));

    f(pMyData == NULL) {
        ExitProcess(1);
    }

    HANDLE handle = CreateThread(
        NULL,
        0,
        MyThreadFunction,
        pMyData,
        0,
        0);

    if (handle == NULL) {
        ExitProcess(2);
    }

    WaitForSingleObject(handle, INFINITE);

    CloseHandle(handle);
    if (pMyData != NULL) {
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pMyData);
        pMyData = NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI MyThreadFunction(LPVOID lpParam) {
    PMYDATA pMyData = (PMYDATA) lpParam;

    // TODO: Сделать что-либо с данными pMyData

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вообще-то, вопрос был, не как сделать поток. Здесь должен быть приведен пример запуска **интерактивного** потока и его взаимодействия с основным потоком из процедуры окна.